# Create a column called df['EV_Sales_Score'] depending on multiple conditions using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe using Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A1kT23', '4523', 'B333', '49O33'],
    'Name': ['Example A', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test123'],
    'Debt_Equity': [-65.56, 0.55, 0, 37],
     'EV_Sales': [9.28, 0.53, 11.3, 45]})
```

I would like to create a column called df['EV_Sales_Score'] depending on multiple conditions.

- If 0 < EV_Sales <=8  EV_Sales_Score shall be 3,
- If 8 < EV_Sales <=10  EV_Sales_Score shall be 2,
- If 10 < EV_Sales <=12  EV_Sales_Score shall be 1 and
- in every other case EV_Sales_Score shall be 0.

How can I solve this?

Comment: another option is `pd.cut(df.EV_Sales, [-np.inf, 0, 8, 10, 12, np.inf], labels=[0, 3, 2, 1, 0], ordered=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via numpy's `select()` method:

```
import numpy as np

conditions=[
((df['EV_Sales'] > 0) & (df['EV_Sales'] <=8)),
((df['EV_Sales'] > 8) & (df['EV_Sales'] <=10)),
((df['EV_Sales'] > 10) & (df['EV_Sales'] <=12))
]
    
labels=[3,2,1]
```

Finally:

```
df['EV_Sales_Score'] =np.select(conditions,labels)
```

Comment: Ty, will the value 8 get the label 3 or 2?

Comment: @Numpy updated Answer...Kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: @Numpy `between()` does not allow one side inclusiveness it allow 2 sides or not at all  so that's why it ruining the logic......so fixed it in the answer

Comment: Ty, but what in any other case, where the score should be 0 for instance if EV_Sales is 45?

Comment: @Numpy numpy's `select()` method has an `default` parameter that has been setted to `0` by default so where condition failed it put `0`....btw you can also explicitly mention it....i.e `df['EV_Sales_Score'] =np.select(conditions,labels,default=0)`

Comment: Ty, sounds great.

Comment: Ty, looks great. I am asking myself which of the solutions is better, the df.loc method or the numpy where method. Both deliver the right solution.

Comment: @Numpy for speedwise  numpy's `select()` is better that `.loc` on bigdatasets it's about 3*times faster than `loc`...even you can test their performance via `timeit` module and `%%timeit` if you are using `jupyter notebook`

Comment: Wowww, ty soooo much, great support ty!!

Answer (score 0):

using pandas `between` does not allow one side inclusiveness.
use this instead:

```
df['EV_Sales_Score'] = 0
df.loc[(df.EV_Sales > 0) & (df.EV_Sales <=8), 'EV_Sales_Score'] = 3
df.loc[(df.EV_Sales > 8) & (df.EV_Sales <=10), 'EV_Sales_Score'] = 2
df.loc[(df.EV_Sales > 10) & (df.EV_Sales <=12), 'EV_Sales_Score'] = 1
```

and so on

Comment: Ty, looks great. I am asking myself which of the solutions is better, your df.loc method or the numpy where method. Both.deliver the right solution.

Comment: both are good!
If you are planning to use pandas a lot, then i recommend to stick with pandas.
it will help you more in the future.

Comment: Ty so much for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution /answer would be using the where method in numpy:

```
df['EV_Sales_Score'] = np.where((0 < df['EV_Sales']) & (df['EV_Sales'] <= 8), 3, 
                  (np.where((8 < df['EV_Sales']) & (df['EV_Sales'] <= 10), 2, 
                  (np.where((10 < df['EV_Sales']) & (df['EV_Sales'] <= 12), 1, 0)))))
```